# Proc contents looping through table names from a different data set

Tags: sas

I am a newbie to SAS and I am trying to execute below code to obtain all the information for a particular library. However it fails in between due to data in a particular dataset. Is there any way to read dataset names from a different dataset and loop through them creating a different dataset specific to each datasetname from the list?

```
Proc contents data= testlib. _ALL_  out=x;
Run;
```

Instead I want something like this

```
Proc contents data in (work. Tbnames) out = x;
 Run;
```

And read data from below data set.

```
Data tbnames(keep tablename) ;
 Set WORK. tablenames;
 Run;
```

Please help
    St

Comment: Are you saying that one of the datasets in the libref TESTLIB is causing PROC CONTENTS to generate error messages? Please show how the libref TESTLIB is defined. Please show the error message you are getting.

Comment: Yes, but there are easier ways to get this type of information. If you explain what you're after from proc contents, like table names or variable names or row counts we can refer you to a better source. Assuming you want table names, use SASHELP.VTABLE or dictionary.table to get information on data sets in a specific library. You can query the table via data step or SQL merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Proc contents data = work.Tbnames out = x;
Run;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `Proc COPY` to copy data sets from one library to another.

```
libname testlib '<os-path-to-folder>';

proc copy in=testlib out=work memtype=DATA;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the data from dictionary.table instead.
This assumes that you have the list of tables in a data set called `tableNames` and it has a variable called `tName`, which is the variable name. Note that it is a case sensitive comparison so `UPCASE()` is used make it all upper case.

```
proc sql;
create table summary as 
select *
from dictionary.table
where memname in (select upcase(tName) from tableNames);
quit;
```

Or look at PROC DATASETS which operates on a library, not a single data set.

```
proc datasets lib=myLib;
run;quit;
```